# How is the weight of Weschler subscales calculated towards general IQ?

Tags: measurement, intelligence, iq

How do the Wechsler IQ (e.g. WAIS III) tests indices (e.g. verbal IQ, performance IQ) and sub-scales contribute to overall IQ? What are the weights of each? If a person scores above 99.9th (maximum) percentile on each index, could their total IQ be estimated on this basis, and if so, what would be their estimated result?

Comment: What is the goal of doing this estimation?